# How To Pass Data Between Components That Not Being Called in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm newbie in Angular but I believe this is a way to pass data between components in Angular using `@Input` :

In parent component :

```
...
<app-child [childMessage]="parentMessage"></app-child>
...
```

In child component :

```
...
@Input() childMessage: string;
...
```

But in my case,

> I can't call my component selector that I want to pass.

And how do I pass the data ?

Ps : What I mean "Call" is doing this --> `<app-child></app-child>`

Comment: your assumption about `@Input`is correct, but I don't get why you can't use the child element selector. Is it because they are not structured in a parent-child structure ?Could you describe a bit more your use case ? And what's the error you get if any ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a shared service between these two components and then set a variable in shared service from parent component and use it in child or you can add getter and setter functions in service

Comment: For you guys that probably have the same problem, for me [this](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/angularjs/1445/angular-services-component-communication) is a good reference to implement communication between components with service in angular.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass in a component value with how you have it structured which i'm guessing doesn't exist. Either use the following to pass in the string.

```
<app-child [childMessage]="'parentMessage'"></app-child>
```

Or in your parent declare the variable you are trying to pass in like so.

```
public parentMessage = "parentMessage";
```

I think this is the problem as the syntax looks correct.

If you are having trouble with rendering the component with its selector like so `<app-child></app-child>` have a look at this [stackblitz from the Angular docs](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jxnjlymxmen) as examples of can be found here of that usage.

This would be likely be fixed by having declarations in your modules set up correctly.